# How do I change an iframe's source from a button click inside another iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, ejs

```
                   <div class="tab-pane"
                         id="viewRateQuote">
                            <iframe id="frame1"
                                     src="page1"></iframe>
                  </div>

                  <div class="tab-pane"
                            <iframe  id="frame2"
                                     src="page2"></iframe>
                  </div>
```

I have 2 iframes inside a parent page (all same domain). They display 2 different pages as tabs . When I click a button inside frame1, I want to set the src of frame2 to src="page3".  If the user go the the parent page, the
src of frame2 is defaulted to page2. It's only that a specific button is clicked inside frame1 that I need to change the source

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To access the parent DOM, you use `parent.document`.

So to change the src of `frame2` from `frame1`, you do:

```
document.getElementById("buttonid").addEventListener("click", function() {
    parent.document.getElementById("frame2").src = "page3";
});
```